# Login Screen in Access with forms, macros and queriesms-

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an embarrassing question regarding Access. I can build relational databases in my sleep but I have always used PHP, mySQL and HTML to build my applications.

I've hated Access with a passion for various reasons ever since I can remember but now I'm stuck using it for a particular project.

I have a number of tables, one of which is `customer`, which among other things has a `username` and `password` field.

When I start the database, I want a login form to appear, which I can do using the `AutoExec` macro, I've made the form with a username and password field. After that, I get stuck with the logic of querying for the username/password and then showing a new form if correct or an error if not.

Could anyone help me out with making the macro and query work together?

Clarification: I am trying to do this without coding whole Visual Basic macros, if at all possible, I want to be able to do it using the macro builder thingumy.

Thanks

Comment: Are you stuck querying base data in Access in general? Are you comfortable with Recordsets?

Comment: I can build queries in Access and I could probably build a query that pops up a dialog box to ask for username and password, then returns the user's record, but linking that query to a fancy form and only opening a new form if the query returns a record is beyond me (in access!).

Comment: astander's approach would be the way to go. yes it does involve a dropping into VBA

Comment: don't be so fritghtened by VBA. You might be able to do this with macros (not sure ...) but try it in VBA. You'll have much more possibilities then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malphas -

It is actually possible to do this without using VBA, but I am wondering whether the reason why you don't want to use VBA is because of the Trust issue.  In which case, this won't be possible, because the macro actions **Close** and **Quit** are disallowed if the database is not trusted.

Whilst you can to run actions in the **AutoExec** macro beyond the point where you use the **OpenForm** command, I think it is neater to continue the next actions on the form itself.  First because you can't really do branching in a macro; secondly because it is more modular to keep actions to do with the form actually on the form.

In the example below, my sample login form is called **LoginForm**, and the username text box is **txtUserName**, and the password text box is called **txtPassword**.

The first thing to do is to protect the dialogue from the simple act of letting the user close the dialogue and escape into the database design screen.  The best way to do this is to set a flag called **ValidLogin** when the form loads.  You will set this flag during the login process.  When the form is closed, check whether the flag is true.  If ValidLogin is false, then close the database.

On the **OnLoad** event of the Login form, click on the ellipsis button, and choose **Macros Builder**.  In the Macro screen, use the following actions (note that the **Condition** column is hidden by default - but you'll only need for the next two macros):

```
Line Condition     Action/Arguments

1                  SetTempVar, Name = ValidLogin, Expression = False
```

On the **OnUnload** event of the Login form, do the same as above, and add:

```
Line Condition     Action/Arguments

1  Not [TempVars]![ValidLogin]
                   Quit, Options = Exit.
```

If you run this now, as soon as you close the form, the database will close.  To be useful, you need to add the following macro actions to the OnClick event of your **Login** button:

```
Line Condition     Action/Arguments

1                  SetTempVar, Name = Valid Login, Expression = DCount("*","Customer","[Username]=[Forms]![LoginForm]![txtUserName] And [Password]=[Forms]![LoginForm]![txtPassword]")>0

2 Not [TempVars]![ValidLogin]
                   MsgBox, Message = Invalid Login
3 ...              StopMacro

4                  OpenForm, Form Name = MainForm

5                  Close, Object Type = Form, Object Name = LoginForm, Save = No
```

Note that in all these examples, I have used embedded macros, not named macros, so you can keep them together with the form.  Also note the ellipsis (...) in the last macro, which represents the value of the last condition.

Comment: In re: no branching in macros: That changes in A2010, and quite powerfully so.

Comment: Re. Branching macros in A2010: Really? About time!  But then again, I never really understood why two macro languages were required in Access!

Comment: Thanks for this, I did manage to work out a solution and this was the most helpful to getting to it!

Answer (score 3):

Given a form frmLogin, with 2 text boxes, txtUserName and txtPassword, and a command button, you can try the following

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim rec As Recordset2

    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username = """ & txtUserName.Value & """ AND password = """ & txtPassword.Value & """")
    If (rec.RecordCount > 0) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a go. Is what I want to do only possible using full on Visual Basic, or can I build this in the macro builder thingy?

Comment: I have not tried doing this with a macro before, but i tmight be possible. This is how i would attempt to do it. You might also want to encrypt the password you are using?

Comment: encryption isn't so much an issue, it isn't a production system, and at this stage, I'm just trying to work out where to start with the theory.

Answer (score -1):

A slight tweak to the above as the code above would be open to SQL injection attacks (yes I know it is only access but it never hurts)

```
Public Function CheckUserPassword(strUserName As String, strPassword As String) As Boolean
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset("tblUsers", dbOpenTable)
With rst
    .Index = "UserName"
    .Seek "=", strUserName
    If .NoMatch = False Then
      If !Password = strPassword Then
        CheckUserPassword = True
    Else
        CheckUserPassword = False
    End If
Else
    CheckUserPassword = False
End If
End With
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Why DBEngine(0)(0) instead of CurrentDB?

Comment: By the way, this code will break if you properly structure your database and split it into back end (tables only) and front end (forms/reports/etc.), because you can't use SEEK on linked tables. Really, Seek is hardly ever helpful, particularly for looking up a single record.

Comment: I was keeping the code simple for a non-split DB, you are right in that the above code would not work for a split design however you can quickly change it to work by doing this

Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(Linked_db_path)
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblUsers", dbOpenTable)

not forgetting to close and set the DB reference to nothing at the end of course.

Oh and DBEngine(0)(0) because I was told a while back that it is quicker than calling CurrentDB. Also a force of habbit when executing queries as I can then get the number of records affected.